# How to make specific UITableViewCell to be visible on screen while having more rows in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am having 20 rows in a table view, and I have designed (or say resized) UITableView in half of the screen (Using IB) and in half screen I am showing the stuff related to particular UITableViewCell. Which cell's details are going to be shown in the half screen is decided runtime. I want the cell being visible while loading the view for say second last cell.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class offers :

```
-(void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
             atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
                     animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

which seems to be what you are looking for.

The [`NSIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) object can be built using :

```
+(NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRow:(NSInteger)row inSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Answer (score 20):

I found the easiest way to ensure that a whole cell is visible is to ask the tableview to make sure that the rect for the cell is visible:

```
[tableView scrollRectToVisible:[tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] animated:YES];
```

An easy way to test it is just to put that into `-(void)tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` - tapping any cell will then scroll it into place if it's partially hidden.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for.  One caveat though... If you have dynamic cell heights (eg. height changes inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath), you'll need extra padding at the bottom of the table.

Comment: Indeed it seems to work much better than the actual method to scroll to an index path

Answer (score 8):

Try [scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
NSUInteger indexArray[] = {1,15};
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexArr length:2];
[yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4** version of Nico teWinkel's answer, which worked best for me:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true) //scrolls cell to middle of screen
}
```

Comment: This code does not take advantage of Cell's rect property for scrolling

Comment: @HrishikeshDevhare No reason to downvote my answer when what you're referring to is obviously a Swift 5 feature or just a completely different method of solving the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** version of Nico teWinkel's answer making use of UITableview's *scroll  rect to visible* method.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
let cellRect = myTableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
myTableView.scrollRectToVisible(cellRect, animated: true)
```

Comment: scrollToRectVisible solution is fundamentally different than scrollToRow. Use scrollToRectVisible is you want to move the table minimally to bring the cell fully into view. Use scrollToRow if you want the cell be be exactly at the top, bottom or in the middle of the view. Both solutions are valid, it depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this,

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row:row, section:section)
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at:indexPath, at:.top, animated:true)
```