# Determine if cell is visible

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `UITableView` and some `UITableviewCell` in it. I have to play the video in every cell (single video at a time).

When I to scroll the table view, if current cell is playing and visible than the video should be continue and if cell is not visible (after scrolling) than video should be stop.

How can I determine that which cell is visible in table view and which is not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157979/how-to-make-specific-uitableviewcell-to-be-visible-on-screen-while-having-more-r

Comment: it automatically get stopped as cell is out of memory try it

Answer (score 3):

You can use this UITableView Delegate method :

```
Add Delegate: UITableViewDelegate

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
// This method is call while cell display                
}
```

Hope its work:

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is figuring out which cells are visible and proceed accordingly, have a look at the code below:

Make sure  your class conforms to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol.

In your `scrollViewDidScroll` you can check which all cells are currently visible using `self.tableview.visibleCells`.

Something like this:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    [mainTableView.visibleCells enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof UITableViewCell * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        //here  you can get indexPath of each cell currently visible when scroll view ends scrolling.

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [mainTableView indexPathForCell:obj];

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement [`didEndDisplaying`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614870-tableview) to learn that the cell has scrolled out of view, and stop playing when you get it.